# Tizen TV Emulator Not Launching in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, haxm, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I am using Mac OS Big Sur, 3.1 Ghz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
I installed Tizen Studio 4.5.1 and install intel Hax (Release HAXM v7.7.0 · intel/haxm · GitHub)
But when I setup the TV emulator and tried to turn ON CPU VT then I get below error
“Failed to launch the emulator. Your system doesn’t support HW virtualization, Try install HAX”
But I already installed HAX so not sure why it still shows the error

Answer (score 0):

I have Big Sur OS and am able to launch the Tizen TV-6.5 Emulator. Could you check this link for troubleshooting HAXM issues.

https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS#Troubleshooting

Comment: I tried reinstall HAXM using silent_install.sh and installed 7.7.0 but no luck. Not sure whether XD/VT is disabled by BIOS. Anything you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to successfully install Tizen Studio on Big Sur was using CLI install: https://medium.com/mobile-application-security-testing-with-nowsecure/how-to-install-tizen-studio-with-cli-207386dc1f82